# PHP (or apache) is preventing asynchronous requests

Tags: apache, concurrency, blocking

It seems that something is preventing two identical PHP requests from executing concurrently. I'm not sure if this is my browser, Apache, or PHP.
I've tested in both Firefox and Chrome (relatively recent versions). Using Apache/2.2.22 (apache2-mpm-prefork) and PHP 5.4.9-4ubuntu2 (libapache2-mod-php5).

I first assumed that this issue would be session related, and tried calling `session_write_close()`, to no avail, even though I'm not using session auto-start. I also used Chrome's Developer Tools and checked in /var/lib/php5, and found nothing relating to any sessions being created.

I've been scratching my head all afternoon with this issue, and cannot find a related question.

I have simplified my test case into a single PHP script (below), please let me know if you can reproduce this, and/or explain this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['frame'])) {
    echo 'Hello world at '. time(). '<br>URI: '. $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    sleep(2);
    exit;
}
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div style="background-color: #eee;">
    <p>If the two times below are different by around 2 seconds (or more), stuff is broken (or not working as I expected).</p>
    <iframe src="<?=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>?frame"></iframe>
    <iframe src="<?=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>?frame"></iframe>
</div>
<hr>
<div style="background-color: #eee;">
    <p>The two iframes below are doing the same thing as the two iframes above, except they have an additional query string parameter, this seems to prevent the scripts from blocking.</p>
    <iframe src="<?=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>?frame&amp;1"></iframe>
    <iframe src="<?=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>?frame&amp;2"></iframe>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Cheers,
David

EDIT: I don't think that this is PHP related, I have managed to reproduce this issue using a CGI script too.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the result of the way HTTP and browsers handle caching. The browser sends a single request assuming it can use the result for both iframes. However, PHP defaults to sending Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate HTTP headers. When the browser sees this header, it sends another request for the second iframe. This is why the second set of iframes works as you expect, because the browser sends two requests immediately, since the URLs are different.